# ¿ Incompatibilidad Middlenware y ExceptionRender LARAVEL 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo Middlenware para controlar el acceso a rutas no permitidas ,sino existe una variable de sessión te envía al abort 502 y SIEMPRE ha funcionado.

Hoy me he puesto a tocar el render para el manejo de las excepciones producidas por Mysql y ahora cuando intento acceder a una ruta sin estar logueado me salta la página del error del Mysql y ya no salta la del abort 502

Middlenware : Siempre ha funcionado :

```
Route::get('HomeJefe', [
    'uses' => 'ControladorJefeDept@index',
    'middleware' => ['ComprobarLogin', 'ComprobarJefeDept']]);
```

Comprobar Login

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {

            if(\Session::has('conectado')){
                 return $next($request);
            }else{
                abort(502);
            } 

        }
```

ComprobarJefeDept

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        $jefe = False;
        $conectado = \Session::get('conectado');


        foreach ($conectado->getRol() as $tipoRol) {
            if ($tipoRol == "Jefe Departamento")
                $jefe = True;
        }

        if ($jefe) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            abort(503);
        }
    }
```

**Exceptions:handler:**

```
 public function render($request, Exception $e) {

        $mensaje = $e->getMessage();
        $mensaje = substr($mensaje, 0, 49);

        if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
        }


        \Session::put('mensaje', $mensaje);
        return redirect('error');  

        // return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

En la ruta:

```
Route::get('error', "ControladorSistema@error");
```

Controlador sistema:

```
class ControladorSistema extends Controller {


    public function error(Request $request){ 
         return view('errors/PagError');
    }
}
```

Desde que puse ese código en el render ya no va al abort(502) sino que va directamente a la view de PagError.

**Solución ::**

En Exception handler con dd se mira el tipo de error que es y se redirecciona:

```
 public function render($request, Exception $e) {



        //dd($e);


        if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Database\QueryException) {
            $mensaje="Problemitas con la bbdd";
            \Session::put('mensaje', $mensaje);
            return redirect('error');
        }

        if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            $mensaje="La pag no existe.";
            \Session::put('mensaje', $mensaje);
            return redirect('error');
        }


        if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
            return parent::render($request, $e);
        }


        //\Session::put('mensaje', $mensaje);
        // return redirect('error');  
        //return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

Comment: No será que `abort()` genera un exception y como vos el único return que dejaste en el `render` es el redirect todo va hacía ahí? Me parece que tendrías que hacer algo similar a lo que está en la documentación. Dentro de tu `if` donde chequeas el tipo de exception pones tu `return`, pero por fuera dejás el que viene por defecto. [The Render Method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#render-method)

Comment: No se me había ocurrido, ya he cogido las expceciones, gracias máquina

Comment: Publicá como respuesta la forma en la que lo resolviste y aceptá tu propia respuesta.