# Cómo incluir Illuminate\Foundation\Application Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Me ha salido este error

```
FatalThrowableError in Facade.php line 215:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::after()

in Facade.php line 215
at Facade::__callStatic('after', array(object(Closure))) in routes.php line 11
at require('C:\xampp\htdocs\MacAltia\app\Http\routes.php') in RouteServiceProvider.php line 41
at RouteServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}(object(Router))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Router)) in Router.php line 354
at Router->group(array('namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'), object(Closure)) in RouteServiceProvider.php line 42
at RouteServiceProvider->map(object(Router))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'map'), array(object(Router))) in Container.php line 507
at Container->call(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'map')) in RouteServiceProvider.php line 72
at RouteServiceProvider->loadRoutes() in RouteServiceProvider.php line 31
at RouteServiceProvider->boot(object(Router)) in RouteServiceProvider.php line 29
at RouteServiceProvider->boot(object(Router))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot'), array(object(Router))) in Container.php line 507
at Container->call(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot')) in Application.php line 734
at Application->bootProvider(object(RouteServiceProvider)) in Application.php line 717
at Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(object(RouteServiceProvider), '17')
at array_walk(array(object(EventServiceProvider), object(RoutingServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider), object(ControllerServiceProvider), object(CookieServiceProvider), object(DatabaseServiceProvider), object(EncryptionServiceProvider), object(FilesystemServiceProvider), object(FormRequestServiceProvider), object(FoundationServiceProvider), object(PaginationServiceProvider), object(SessionServiceProvider), object(ValidationServiceProvider), object(ViewServiceProvider), object(AppServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider), object(EventServiceProvider), object(RouteServiceProvider), object(ServiceProvider)), object(Closure)) in Application.php line 718
at Application->boot() in BootProviders.php line 17
at BootProviders->bootstrap(object(Application)) in Application.php line 203
at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders')) in Kernel.php line 222
at Kernel->bootstrap() in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Al intentar ejecutar este código en routes.php

```
App::after(function ($request, $response) {
    // Mencegah Kembali Login Setelah Logout dengan Menekan Tombol Back pada Browser
    $response->headers->set("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store, must-revalidate");
    $response->headers->set("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    $response->headers->set("Expires"," Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
});
```

Yo creo que es porque no tengo la "línea" en require dev pero no lo sé.
Quisiera poner la línea esa en el require dev, actualizar composer y luego otra línea en aliases...

Pero no sé qué línea tengo que poner en composer->require-dev y luego en aliases, ando perdido, puede que el error se de por otra cosa, no lo sé ...

Edito para poner la solución :

Seguir estos pasos:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118998/prevent-browsers-back-button-login-after-logout-in-laravel-5/30119257#30119257

Comment: Qué versión de Laravel estás usando? De dónde sacaste `after()`, tenés el link de la documentación?

Comment: http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/prevent-back-login-after-logout-by-hitting-the-back-button-on-your-browser

Comment: Versión 5.1 Quiero ejecutar ese código para que cuando un usuario se desconecte no pueda volver atrás con las flechas del navegador, me pasaron ese enlace, pero me da error que mencioné arriba.

Comment: No recuerdo haber visto ese método en Laravel 5, es de Laravel 4. De todas formas, no se cuanto sentido tiene hacer algo así, la realidad es que si está deslogueado, no va a poder hacer nada, en cuanto quiera cargar una URL para la que necesite estar logueado, no va a poder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30119257/1095101

Comment: Entiendo perfectamente lo que quieres decir, pero la vista anterior se cargaría : Aunque no puedas ejecutar ninguna acción si estabas con datos delicados y una persona le da hacía atrás podría verlos, eso es un problema de seguridad importante

Comment: En el link que te pasé, la 2da y 3er respuesta explican como hacerlo con middlewares. Si lo lográs hacer, publicalo acá como respuesta.

Comment: El middleware que se pone finalmente en routes es para el lado del servidor,se trata de que el cliente no pueda volver.... y me da un error...

Comment: He creado el middelware RevalidateBackHistory, lo he añadido en kernel.php, se lo he puesto a Route::group(['middleware' => ['ComprobarLogin', 'JefeOrRoot','preventBackHistory']], function() { } y ha dao error

Comment: Se te cruzaron los ejemplos. Creaste el middleare `RevalidateBackHistory` y en el la ruta estás usando `preventBackHistory`. Deberías usar `revalidate` (siguiendo el ejemplo del link).

Comment: Perfecto,muchas gracias, pero no entiendo como actua el middleware del servidor, cuando la acción de ir hacía atrás es del navegador del cliente por tanto no hay ninguna petición de cliente->servidor para que se active el route::

Comment: No estoy 100% seguro, pero creo que podes ir hacía atrás y ver la página anterior en la medida en la que cuando se cargó esa página la primera vez, algún header haya permitido cachearla. Los headers que seteas en el middleware son para la primer carga, no para cuando vas hacia atrás, porque como bien decís, ahí no estarías impactando en el server. El tema es que ya se le indicó al explorador que esa página no tenía que ser guardada. Insisto, es lo que deduzco, no estoy seguro.

Comment: muchas gracias por todo, podrías ayudarme con este asunto ?  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125285/incompatibilidad-middlenware-y-exceptionrender-laravel-5-1